# how to find post by using findUnique in prisma with post id and prodCode

Tags: javascript, orm, prisma

I want to find only one post matching by post id and prodCode

below is my query code. It doesn't work.
If i change findUnique to findFirst. it works.

```
const post = await client.post.findUnique({
          where: {
            AND: [
              { id: postId },
              {
                product: {
                  prodCode,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        });
```

prisma model

```
model Product {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  prodName String
  prodCode String    @unique
  posts    Post[]
  holdings Holding[]
  proposes Propose[]

}

model Post {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
  product   Product  @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId Int
  title     String
  content   String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Post.id` is unique, you don't *need to* filter by `prodCode` as well. You could just query the `post` record with the needed `id` and then check if the connected `product` has the right `prodCode`.

I would just do this:

```js
const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: postId
    },
    include: {
      product: true
    }
  });

  if (post.product.prodCode === prodCode) {
    // No result for desired query
  } else {
    // "post" variable contains result of desired query
  }
```